# Least square estimators for "no slope" and "no intercept" models.

Tags: linear-regression

I'm trying to understand simple linear regression. Here is a problem I'm working on, and I'm trying to understand the answers conceptually.

I want to find the least square estimators $b_1$ and $b_0$ for the following:

(a) The "no slope" model $Y_i = \beta_0 + \epsilon_i$, and

(b) The "no intercept" model $Y_i = \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$.

To do this, I know that I will need to minimize the function $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \epsilon_i^{2}$. Thus, I have

(a) $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \epsilon_i^{2} = (Y_i-\beta_0)^2$. Now minimizing this yields,

$0=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} -2(Y_i-b_0) \Rightarrow 0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i-nb_0 \Rightarrow b_0 = \overline{Y}$.

(b) similarly for this part, I get that $b_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{2}}$.

I understand that part (a) makes intuitive sense -- if there is no slope, then the regression line is a horizontal line with value $\beta_0$. So, even though $\beta_0$ is an unknown parameter, we can still reason that the best estimate would be whatever its value is. I'm looking for a way to understand the answer for part (b) in the same way (it seems less intuitive to me). Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The algebraic part:
$$R(b_1)=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-b_1X_i)^2\\
R'(b_1)=2\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-b_1X_i)(-X_i)=-2\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i+2b_1\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
b_1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}.$$
The geometric (intuitive) part:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

Note that the numerator is the sum of areas of brown rectangles $X_iY_i$ and the denominator is the sum of the areas of green rectangles $X_i^2$. And their ratio (the relative weights) determines the slope of the line. Obviously, the total green area is bigger, hence the line is flatter.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to your question about (b)
is that this is the way the math works out -
nothing more, nothing less.

Since this is probably unsatisfactory,
I have come up with this:

The slope for each point is
$\dfrac{y_i}{x_i}=s_i$.
Therefore,
if the result is of the form
$\dfrac{\sum u_i}{\sum v_i}$,
then we "should" have
$u_i = v_is_i$,
so the slopes weight the data.
If $s_i = s$ for all $i$,
then we want
$s 
=\dfrac{\sum u_i}{\sum v_i}
=\dfrac{\sum v_is_i}{\sum v_i}
=s
$,
but to ensure that
$\sum v_i \ne 0$,
the simplest way is to have
$v_i = x_i^2$.
Then
$u_i = v_is_i
=x_iy_i$.

Of course,
while doing this
my hands are waving so fast
that I might take flight.
But this is the best that I can do
right now.

As I wrote at the start,
it is really the fact that
this is the way the math works out.